# CLSQL trouble using MySQL as backend on windows

Tags: mysql, common-lisp, clsql

I'm using SBCL on Windows. I got an error When I attempted to connect MYSQL using CLSQL like this.

```
(ql:quickload :clsql)
(clsql:connect '("localhost" "database-name" "database-user-name" "password") 
         :database-type :mysql) 
Couldn't load foreign libraries "libmysqlclient", "libmysql". (searched CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-   SEARCH-PATHS*: (#P"C:/Users/Razenrote/AppData/Roaming/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/clsql-20140316-git/db-mysql/"))
```

Comment: You have to [tell Windows how to find the DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications).  The easiest way is to put that directory in the `PATH` environment variable.  Depending on the Windows version, you can also use `SetDllDirectory` (XP SP1 +) or `AddDllDirectory`/`RemoveDllDirectory`/`SetDefaultDllDirectories` (8+, or Vista/7 with KB2533623).

Comment: @acelent I tried but completely failed. After Installing `MySQL C Connector`, I add the directory which includes `libmysql.dll` into `PATH` environmental variable. But,, I can't still load it.

Comment: Anyone who are using `CL-MYSQL` on Windows? Now I'm trying to use `CL-MYSQL` on Ubuntu x86.

Comment: Try debugging the problem with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), you might find other directories you'll have to include in `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A note at the bottom of the clsql home page (http://www.cliki.net/CLSQL) addresses your issue.

Comment: Thanks @user1597986! But I got the same result after inserting library paths

Comment: (clsql:push-library-path #p"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib") doesn't work.